# Cycle through a repeating vector without explicitly writing out the repeated occurrences

Tags: matlab, vector, repeat

The question is difficult to explain without an example.

Say I have a vector,

```
v = [1 1 1 0 0];
```

and I want to loop through each element of *v* until I get to the end, then go from the beginning again etc, i.e. the vector is repeated.

```
for i = 1:300
    answer = v(i);
end
```

Is there a way to make this work without replacing vector *v* with a repeated version of the vector:

```
v2 = [1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 ...];
```

(I want to avoid storing a long vector in the memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So if you're just trying to replicate the matrix use `repmat` like

(assuming: `n = 300;  m = numel(v);`)

```
v2 = repmat(v1, 1, (n/m))
```

But if you're asking how to get a loop to index through the vector one element at a time, 60 times (for whatever reason) then you could do it using `mod`:

```
for i = mod(0:(n-1), m)+1
     %// do stuff with v(i)
end
```

Or the more explicit (and easier to read) obvious solution would be a nested loop:

```
for j = 1:(n/m)
    for i = 1:m;
        %// do stuff with v(i)
    end
end
```

Comment: @user3448606 why not just use the nested loop though?

Comment: I have simplified the problem here but in my project speed is critical and there would be several hundred lines of code inside the extra loop, unnecessarily. Also n is not necessarily a multiple of m. And finally can I suggest an edit: 'for i = mod(0:n-1,m)+1' is technically correct I think.